# get values from each sheet of workbook of range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to get values of each cell of given ranges  (ranges are in array (rangeAdd) and in form of "M1:T14") from all sheets in array (value of one sheet shall be in one row of array). My code is as follow,

```
async function getDataFromEachSheet(rangeAdd) {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.load("items/name");
    await context.sync();
    sheets.items.forEach( (sheet) =>{
      var a =[]
      for (const currentRange of rangeAdd) {
        var range = sheet.getRange(currentRange);
        range.load("values");
        context.sync();
        console.log(range.values)
        var arr = [];
        arr = range.values
        var a = arr.join().split(',')
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I am getting

1."Unhandled promise rejection" and

2."The property 'values' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context."

I am not able to use await context.sync() instead of context.sync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of Avoid using the context.sync method in loops https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern. I have managed to get Values with following code.

```
    async function getDataFromEachSheet(rangeAdd) {
      try {
      await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const sheets = context.workbook.worksheets.load("items/name");
        await context.sync();
        var rangeObj = [];
        sheets.items.forEach((sheet) => {
          rangeAdd.forEach((currentRange) => {
            const range = sheet.getRange(currentRange).load("values") ;
            rangeObj.push(range);
          });
        });
        await context.sync();
        console.log(rangeObj)
      })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `await context.sync()` you can try using `return context.sync().then()`. So the updated code might look something like this:

```
async function getDataFromEachSheet(rangeAdd) {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.load("items/name");
    await context.sync();
    sheets.items.forEach((sheet) => {
      var a = []
      for (const currentRange of rangeAdd) {
        var range = sheet.getRange(currentRange);
        range.load("values");
        return context.sync().then(()=>{
          console.log(range.values)
          var arr = [];
          arr = range.values
          var a = arr.join().split(',')
        })
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for guidance. After return context.sync().then(), I am getting values from first range of first sheet only. for other range of first sheet and all other sheets, i am getting  same error. 1."Unhandled promise rejection" and
2."The property 'values' is not available.